# Does Phaser render sprites with visible set to false?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Does Phaser render sprites with visible set to false?

I'm making a game much like Motherload but with infinite terrain. The terrain generates as you go along and is made of 64x64 sized sprites (tiles), as you can imagine as you go along alot of sprites are added to the scene. Sprites which go out of view have their visible property set to false however my frame rate (FPS) drops considerably as the player goes along and alot of terrain is generated. Why is this if only the sprites on screen have their visible property set to true? I have checked over and over again that only the sprites on screen have their visible property set to true and don't understand why my FPS drops so much as I go along, is Phaser still rendering these sprites with visible set to false?

Comment: I imagine even though you set visibility to false, the old terrain remains in memory causing performance issues. Could you implement a pool of terrain sprites, enough to fill the scene. Them simple loop through them, when a sprite is out of the scene it goes back into the pool to be put into the scene where needed? Similar to how people do it for bullet pools. Then your not creating elements when in the game loop.

Comment: @ste2425 Should I remove (destroy) the tiles when they go out of view and store them in memory? I don't understand why they cause this performance impact anyhow as they have visible set to false (so shouldn't be rendered?), aren't being updated or have any physics checks. I checked what was causing the FPS drop using Chrome's Javascript profiler and it is the render loop causing this drop which is why I believe they are still being rendered despite being off-screen and having visible set to false.

Comment: After some reading apparently sprite.kill() halts rendering of that sprite, I will give this a shot and see if it helps with the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of constantly creating new Sprites and then `.kill()`ing them, you should be recycling Sprites.

Here's an example on [Recycling.](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/groups/recycling)

It's the same technique used in Particle Effects (so that if a particle generator runs for infinity, it only creates a finite number of particles)

Here's the steps to use:

1. Create a number of sprites (probably 2x the size of your screen) in a `Phaser.Group`
2. render the initial scene (position, image) for each sprite
3. As a sprite moves off-screen (check in `update` using [`sprite.inCamera`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.1/Phaser.Sprite.html#inCamera) ) then `.kill()` it.
4. When it's time to draw a new sprite on the screen, use `getFirstExists(false)` to get a re-used sprite that's *not visible*.
5. update the sprite's image and position
6. tell the game to render the sprite using `.revive()`

And voila!  You'll see a massive performance increase.  (especially if you were trying to create 1,000s of sprites before)